# How to make randomly Spawned Images on Website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add the konami code to my website. I have the keys and everything working there but what I am trying to accomplish is that when a user types in the konami code and presses space an image of a potato (or different potatoes) will spawn randomly on the screen. The website should be disabled while this is going on until the viewer refreshes.

I have been Googling but I'm not sure if I am describing it right. Does anyone know how to do this to perhaps provide a jsfiddle or guide.

I would prefer to do this in Javascript.

Comment: Do you have the images on the server?

Comment: Yes. I do have the image.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (window.addEventListener) {
  var state = 0,
    konami = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65];
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == konami[state]) state++;
    else state = 0;
    if (state == 10)
      <!--window.location = "http://www.teroromighty.com/site";  //you can write your own code here-->

      <!--Wild Potatoes-->

      input = document.getElementById("in");
    length = 1;
    input.onkeypress = function() {
      //user pressed a key
      if (input.value.split(" ").length == length) {
        length++;
        //input has a space
        //let the magic happen
        //repeat endless
        potato = document.createElement("img");
        potato.src = "potato.jpg";
        potato.style.left = MATH.random(0, 90) + "%";
        potato.style.top = MATH.random(0, 90) + "%";
        potato.style.position = "fixed";
        potato.style.zIndex = "100";
        //add to body
        document.all.body.appendChild(potato);
      }
    }
  }, true);
}
```

Comment: And add: if(state==10){konami()}

Comment: And use // to comment inside js

Comment: this is probably incredibly simple but I am still not getting it. Here is the site it is currently implemented on. http://teroromighty.com/

Comment: (On mobile -> bad to debug) what does the error console tell you?

Comment: says: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list